# How to set a prefix to bash verbose mode

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a script using verbose mode but I'd like to set a prefix to the command outputs (mainly to make the output look nicer).

For example, the script:

```
#!/bin/bash -v

pwd
hostname
```

This will give the output:

```
pwd
/home/username
hostname
myawesomehost
```

But I'd like the output (specifically with the `$` sign):

```
$ pwd
/home/username
$ hostname
myawesomehost
```

Is there a way to set a prefix for the verbose output like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `PS4` with `set -x` (enable trace):

```
#!/bin/bash

# prompt for trace commands
PS4='$ '

# enable trace
set -x

# remaining script
pwd
hostname
```

This will produce output as:

```
$ pwd
/home/username
$ hostname
myawesomehost
```

Comment: The only issue I have with this solution is that `-x` will print embedded commands twice, such that `echo "$(pwd)"` will output `$$ pwd`. Is there a way to prevent that with `-x`?

Comment: Hmm I'm note sure how to avoid `$$` for command substitution. I will try to find something.